# How to search for text within compressed files and get just the files name

Tags: grep, filenames, gzip

I'm trying to find just the files' names which contain an specific string. The files are compressed (`.gz`).

I don't have `zgrep` installed and can't install it. Therefore I can't use the `-l` option.

I've tried using `gzip` and `gunzip` with the `-c` option and pipping to `grep -l` but that did not work, I have also used `zcat` but that also did not work. Any clue?

(Note: the OS is Solaris 10).

Comment: is it a tar.gz file?

Comment: What is mean is it one tar.gz with multiple files in it or each file is gziped separately?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes the files are ".tar.gz" and all are individual files. (All are compressed logs). Thanks.

Comment: From your `grep: illegal option -- q Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file`, you're on Solaris 10 or earlier right?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneChazelas, yes, you are right, it's a Solaris 10 (5.10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the work of zgrep manually. Since you only want the file names, use `grep` just to test the presence of the pattern, and print out the file name if the pattern is found.

```
#!/bin/sh
pattern=$1; shift
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH # needed on Solaris 10 and earlier
                          # to get a standard grep
export PATH
found=0
for x do
  if case "$x" in
      *.gz|*.[zZ]) <"$x" gzip -dc | grep -q -e "$pattern";;
      *) <"$x" grep -q -e "$pattern";; 
     esac
  then
    found=1
    printf '%s\n' "$x"
  fi
done
if [ $found -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

To be run as:

```
that-script 'pattern' file1 file2.gz file3.Z file.*.gz ...
```

A few notes specific to you running Solaris 10 (also applies to earlier versions and in some respects to Solaris 11 as well).

- on those systems, `/bin/sh` is a Bourne shell as opposed to a standard POSIX `sh`. You've got the choice of either changing your she-bang to `#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh -` to get a standard `sh`, or restrict yourself to the ancient Bourne syntax like we do here (so no `$(...)`, no `case $x in (x)...`) (Solaris 11 is now using a POSIX compliant shell for its `/bin/sh` (ksh93)).
- on those systems, `zcat` only handles `.Z` files as compressed by `compress` as they were in the olden days. You need to invoke `gzip` for `.gz` files.
- By default, you don't necessarily get standard utilities. For instance, the default `grep` in `/usr/bin` is an ancient one that doesn't support the standard `-q` option. To get the standard utilities, you need to update `$PATH` with the paths where to find the standard utilities (as output by `getconf PATH`).

If you want to display both the archive member name and the line number or content, you'll need to get the line data from grep and the member name from the script. Remove the `-q` option from the `grep` invocation, and postprocess its content.

```
#!/bin/ksh
pattern=$1; shift
export PATH="$(getconf PATH):$PATH" # needed on Solaris 10 and earlier
                                    # to get a standard grep
found=0
for x do
  case "$x" in
      *.gz|*.[zZ]) <"$x" gzip -dc | grep -n -e "$pattern";;
      *) <"$x" grep -n -e "$pattern";; 
  esac | {
    filename=$x awk '{print ENVIRON["filename"] ":" $0; found=1}
                     END {exit(!found)}' && found=1
  }
done
if [ $found -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
```

Comment: `zcat -f` and avoid the `case`

Comment: @roaima That also treats non-`.gz` files differently, in particular that will search through the first file of a zip file only. I'm not sure that's desirable, I think I'd prefer text in zip files to be skipped altogether than found only if it's in the first member. I could add a case for `.zip` files, but `zcat -f` doesn't scale that way.

Comment: Oh ok. I'd not considered `zip` files as they weren't mentioned; just `gz` and plain.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, where am I supposed to add the patter and file information (like *.gz).

Comment: @Luis I don't understand the question. Do you want to add support for other file types?

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Chazelas, would it be too much modification to the script, to make the output to display the file and the whole line where the string has been found? e.g.: file:line. Thanks.

Comment: @Luis See my edit (untested)

Comment: Hi @Gilles, thanks for your additions. I've run your script  but for some reason I get the same output as with the other one, that is, just the file information. Working on understanding it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Grab the pattern, just like grep
re="$1"; shift

# Loop across the remaining arguments, or stdin if none
test 0 -eq $# && set -- -
for file
do
    # Search through the file (compressed or otherwise)
    zcat -f "$file" | grep -q "$re" && echo "$file"
done
```

You should copy this into a file and make that file executable (`chmod a+x {filename}`, and then use it similarly to `zgrep`:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"  # Add the ~/bin directory to your PATH. Also add this line to your ~/.profile

cat > ~/bin/mygrep             # Paste the file at this point, hit Ctrl/D on a blank line to end. Or otherwise edit ~/bin/mygrep
chmod a+x ~/bin/mygrep         # Make it executable

mygrep 'hello.*world' a*       # Search for the RE 'hello.*world' in all files beginning with 'a'
```

---

If you find that `zcat -f` or `grep -q` aren't recognised you can swap each for the following

```
( zcat "$file" 2>/dev/null || cat "$file" )    # zcat -f "$file"
grep "$re" 2>/dev/null                         # grep -q "$re"
```

With both substitutions applied the resulting replacement line would look like this

```
( zcat "$file" 2>/dev/null || cat "$file" ) | grep "$re" 2>/dev/null && echo "$file"
```

Comment: Hi Roaima, thanks for your answer. Where am I supposed to place the file and pattern information?, Like this?

`re="$the_desired_pattern"; shift`  and `for *.gz`

Comment: @Luis, no. you use it like you would use `zgrep`. I'll update the question with the information. (The same goes for Gilles' answer.)

Comment: Thanks @roaima, it looks like my grep and gzip version do not support some of the options in the script,

Invalid Option
Usage: zcat [file ...]
grep: illegal option -- q
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: Thanks @roaima for taking the time. This has been quite helpful.

Comment: @Luis I've updated the answer with possible alternatives for you

Answer (score 1):

Since your files are actually tar.gz file you need to untar them as well. Tar is a archiving utility that packages multiple files together (in your case only one) and was originally used to backup data to tape drives.

The tar utility did not originally compress content hence why it was usually streamed through gzip or other utilities for compression.. if you unzip a tar.gz you are still left with the tar achieving layer which is why it is not working.

these days gun tar will tar and zip for you in one command using the "z" command.

so in order for you to do what you want I think you need to do use the tar extract "x" unzip "z" from a file target "f" and stream to stdout "O" then pipe to grep. It should look something like this:

```
 tar -xzf mycompressedlogfile.tar.gz -O | grep -l "pattern"
```

Since your tar version does not have -z then try piping the output of gzip through tar before your grep

```
 gzip -dc mycompressedlogfile.tar.gz | tar -xOf - | grep -l "pattern"
```

But I do not think Solaris 10 version of tar support the "O" option to stream the tar content to stdout. :( You are probably going to have to do the above (without the O so "tar -xf -") for each file from within a working directory, or some way to make sure you can account for the files that are created, search the content, and then delete the file(s). Sorry unless you can install gnu-tar on the Solaris machine.

I guess from the answer selected you were able to search the tar stream for the pattern (since it is not compressed I guess that makes sense) and figure it out from there.. :) good deal.

Glad you got your answer.

Comment: Hi @Rob , thanks for the information. Unfortunately the deployed tar version is an old one. I does not have the `-z` option available.

Comment: I updated my post, but I think you are not going to be able to do it since from the Solaris man page for tar that I found, the "O" option is not available so you will not be able to stream the content of the tar to standard out. At least I do not know of a way.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for taking the time. Yes, the tar version deployed on the server does not have the `O` option.

Comment: You are most welcome.. I am glad someone got you an answer that worked out :). Even it was not me.